# How to access web page via terminal?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, command-line-interface

I am testing an Apache server.  Normally I open `x.x.x.x/directory/index.php` in Firefox, then  read the `httpd/error_logs` and troubleshoot.

My question is, what if I don’t have a Web browser (e.g., Chrome/Firefox) on my test system?  How can I do an equivalent test via the terminal?  I tried `ping x.x.x.x/directory/index.php` but it doesn’t work that way.

Comment: Try curl, wget, lynx, links, w3m, ...

Answer (score 8):

> My question is, what if I don’t have Chrome/Firefox on? How can I do
>   the equivalent test via the terminal? I tried `ping
>   x.x.x.x/directory/index.php` but it doesn’t work that way.

Using [`ping`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) would never work. All `ping` does is send/receive ICMP packets from a network address. So in your example, the only thing you could actually “ping” is `ping x.x.x.x` with the remainder of the URL (`/directory/index.php`) just choking `ping` as it attempts to resolve the *whole* URL as if it were a hostname. The error would be something like:

```
ping: cannot resolve x.x.x.x/directory/index.php: Unknown host
```

But for the specific type of web server testing/debugging you are looking for, I usually use [`curl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) but specifically I use `curl -I -L` which will throw back just basic response headers and follow any location redirects the server might have in place; the `-I` flag tells `curl` to just show the header and `-L` flag tells `curl` to follow any server redirects it encounters.

For example, if I run this `curl -I -L` command on `google.com`:

```
curl -I -L google.com
```

I get the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 24 Aug 2015 02:16:32 GMT
Expires: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 02:16:32 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 24 Aug 2015 02:16:32 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=1111111111111111:FF=0:TM=1440382592:LM=1440382592:V=1:S=5ToXkoBHyK2BAjyf; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-2015 16:02:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=70=VKM1D8HeCMlye1YjMDYSqPlyIpPHKkitAor--wiqYznamENfNig69ZBW5oBgIR7wOFzVaUB6i4WKj-tqa2WcqbOCeVTc0hB4xQWQzBxpNazPp_20dBiU4in0wIop8mhz; expires=Tue, 23-Feb-2016 02:16:32 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Note there are two headers returned:

- `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`
- `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`

This is useful not just for Apache server testing but also useful for debugging [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rewrite rules and such.

This `curl -I -L` method is far more useful and efficient than using a visual browser like Chrome or Firefox since those programs are designed to optimize browsing speed by caching content. Which means you can make an adjustment to your Apache server one second, but the visual browser won’t necessarily show the change right away unless you clear the cache or force the page to reload a few times. The `curl -I -L` shows you exactly what the server at that moment is doing in response to your request which is exactly what you want/need when debugging server configs.

Answer (score 6):

The command you want is either `curl` or `wget` (depending on your personal preferences).  These commands make a HTTP request to the server.  They're not great for simulating the load of an entire page (they don't, by default, load the assets referenced by the HTML page, and they can't execute javascript or interact with the page at all), but it doesn't sound like you're after anything that advanced.  So, `curl` or `wget` will almost certainly work fine for you.

Answer (score 3):

@womble is right. However, if you don't have `curl` or `wget`, you can use telnet:

```
telnet x.x.x.x 80
GET /directory/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: x.x.x.x
```

Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time (for the end of headers) and you’ll get the raw HTML. You may have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Unix) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (Windows) to exit if the server uses keepalive.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use a **text based browser**. This option will let you traverse the web page and test more of its components. Things like forms for example, since it is a full-fledged browser.

Use **lynx**, or its younger brother **links**, or **elinks**.

Comment: elinks worked the best. lynx wasn't able to display a table properly, the cells were out of the column position and links wasn't able to save the output to file.

Answer (score 2):

You can issue a GET request with OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -connect cdn.sstatic.net:443 <<eof
GET /stackexchange/js/universal-login.js HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: cdn.sstatic.net

eof
```

Note that you can also use "HTTP/2", but be careful because some servers
(e.g. github.com) do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually view the page, I would recommend using `Lynx`, which was one of Michael Hampton's recommendations. It renders the HTML and the page can be interacted with via the keyboard. Just don't expect any fancy animations or pictures. :)

It is available via virtually all package managers, the ones on Mac OS X included.